# My IF property is being ignored in my class when i use it

Tags: c#, class, constructor, properties

```
public class Irritante : Child   
{
    /*Fields*/
    private int ir_numeroBirras;
    private double ir_mediaBirras; 

    /*Properties*/
    public int NumeroBirras
    {
        get { return ir_numeroBirras; }
        set { if (value > 0) ir_numeroBirras = value; }
    }
    public double MediaBirras
    {
        get { return ir_mediaBirras; }
        set { ir_mediaBirras = value; }
    }
    //Constructor
    public Irritante(string nome, int idade, int numBirras, double mediaDasBirras) : base(nome, idade)
    {
        NumeroBirras = numBirras;
        ir_mediaBirras = mediaDasBirras;
    }
```

When i try to use the contructor **Irritante** with the property **NumeroBirras** it is ignoring the **if(value>0)**
This means i can still add a 0 to this field with client code, which i should not be able to, any tips? i cant find it anywhere

Comment: You can't add 0 as value to NumeroBirras, but the default value of ir_numeroBirras is 0.

Comment: It is because default integer value is 0. What do you want if you want to set 0 ?

Comment: Ok, the default is 0, if the value is not above 0 it puts 0 on ir_numeroBirras?

Comment: Sorry but it is not clear what you are asking. What do you want to set `ir_numeroBirras` if the value <=0 ?

Comment: just change  public int NumeroBirras and (ir_numeroBirras) to  public int? NumeroBirras

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default value of `ir_numeroBirras` is `0`. You can't put a `0` using the property. But if you test using a `0` as parameter value, you are being fooled by the default value.

If you're talking about you shouldn't put a 0 in the parameter of Irritante ctor, that's quite different

```
public Irritante(string name, int idade, int numBirras, double mediaDasBirras) : base(nome, idade) 
{
   if(numBirras < 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(numBirras), "Hey, you can't drink 0 beers");
   ir_numeroBirras = numBirras;
   ir_mediaBirras = mediaDasBirras;
}
```